# How to mock behavior for Springockito mocks?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, springmockito

If I create a mock in my spring context file using Springockito as described [here](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home), how do I mock some behavior for it?

What I'm trying to do:

1. ClassA is being tested.
2. ClassB is autowired in ClassA.
3. ClassB is being mocked with Springockito.
4. ClassA needs ClassB to do something in its PostConstruct.
5. I need to mock ClassB to do that something, since it can't and shouldn't really do it.

Doing this is straight forward without using Springockito (using Mockito straight up), but I need to autowire these beans and use Spring in my tests. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Springockito, but it looks interesting for some narrow cases - namely integration testing with mocking just a bit.

Anyway, it looks like for a straightforward use case you extend [AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.html), you could also autowire ClassB in your test just like you do in ClassA.  Then you could define your expected behavior for ClassB in your setup method.

But I think that you need to set up some behavior for the ClassB bean before you get access to it in your setup method.  In that case, you may need another bean to set up ClassB to do the expected behavior.  So your testContext.xml would have something like this in it:

```
<bean id="classA" class="com.jarvis.ClassA" depends-on="classBMockSetter" />
<mockito:mock id="classB" class="com.jarvis.ClassB" />
<bean id="classBMockSetter" class="com.jarvis.test.ClassBMockSetter">
  <property name="classB" ref="classB" />
</bean>
```

The ClassBMockSetter would look something like:

```
public class ClassBMockSetter {
  private ClassB classB;
  public void setClassB(ClassB classB) {
    this.classB = classB;
    given(classB.foo()).willReturn(true);
    given(classB.bar()).willReturn(42);
  }
}
```

I think that would work, but at that point, isn't it easier to just hand-code your mock ClassB?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. When you say hand code the mock, where would the code live, since it needs to be when ClassA is instantiated in ClassATest and before the post construct method gets called.

Answer (score 3):

Note that new [springockito-annotations](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations) help to achieve the same goal without messing with xml context and extra helper classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class, locations = "classpath:test-config.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MemoAutoTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA;
    @Autowired @ReplaceWithMock
    private ClassB classB;

    @Test
    public void testClassA() {
        // stub B 
        when(classB.foo()).thenReturn(true);
        when(classB.bar()).thenReturn(42);

        // test A
    }

}
```

This would cause ClassB to be replaced with mock at main application context initialization.

Comment: Can you please share test-config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

What is worked for me is using *@InjectMocks* notation.
(See https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home)

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class, locations = "classpath:test-config.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MemoAutoTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

```
@Autowired
private ClassA classA;
@Autowired @InjectMocks
private ClassB classB;

@Test
public void testClassA() {
    // stub B 
    when(classB.foo()).thenReturn(true);
    when(classB.bar()).thenReturn(42);

    // test A
    classA.doSomethingThatInternallyCallClassBFoo();
}
```

}